# Excel VBA finding the upper and lower bound of a number automatically

Tags: excel, vba

[image: list of values]

I am trying to find the upper and lower bound of a number by using Excel VBA but I have no idea how to write the code for that. So for example, I am given the number 35 (Cell E6). And in the list of values (in column A) that I am given, I want the program to automatically find 30 and 40 respectively and store the values beside 30 and 40 in 2 variables for some further calculations. Is that possible? Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: how are 30 and 40 determined to be the upper and lower bound? is it in the data? share a screenshot of your data and also any code you have tried to solve your problem. SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Hi sorry I did not realize that my picture wasn't up just now. I have just added a link there which shows the example data.

Comment: You should work through this series till you can solve your question:[Excel VBA Introduction Part 1 - Getting Started in the VB Editor](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=KHO5NIcZAc4&index=1&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: I can sort of deduce from the screenshot that upper bounds = 40 and lower bounds = 30 but it is a guess.  I understand that you are new to StackOverflow(SO) and new to coding but at the very least you should write your posts so that the readers do not have to guess what you are trying to do,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Office 365, that would be a good occasion to use the brand new Excel XLOOKUP function which is also available in VBA.

For example:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("MyWorkbook.xlsm")

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim LowerBound As Long
Dim UpperBound As Long

With ws
    LowerBound = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(.Range("E6"), .Range("$A$1:$A$1000"), .Range("$A$1:$A$1000"), CVErr(xlErrValue), -1, 1)
    UpperBound = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(.Range("E6"), .Range("$A$1:$A$1000"), .Range("$A$1:$A$1000"), CVErr(xlErrValue), 1, 1)
End With

Debug.Print LowerBound
Debug.Print UpperBound
```

[More details on how to use XLOOKUP](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-xlookup/ba-p/811376)

The key here is to use the 5th argument of the function (match mode) to your advantage. To get the "lower bound" we ask for the exact match or next smaller and for the "upper bound" we ask for the exact match or next larger.

[image]

**Caveats and notes:**

- In the code above, the `lookup_array` and the `return_array` ranges are hardcoded, but it would be better to simply define a range object and refer to it instead.
- If the `lookup_value` is greater than the biggest number in the `lookup_array`, it will give you a run-time error or the returned value will be 0.
- Make sure you have the [Immediate Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/use-the-immediate-window) visible (Ctrl+G) if you want to see the results of the `Debug.Print` statements.